# Excel Countifs with offset function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have a data set where I am using countifs and offset to change the column reference as I pull down the formula.

Here is my formula:

```
=COUNTIFS('Student Survey (Middle)'!B:B,'Middle Master'!A2,OFFSET('Student Survey (Middle)'!G:G,0,ROW()-4,1240,1),"agree")
```

any idea why this is returning #Value?

Comment: The ranges need to be the same size, you are doing the full column on the first but only 1240 rows on the second. Try getting rid of the `,1240,1` part completely, it is optional.

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of the volatile OFFSET and use:

```
=COUNTIFS('Student Survey (Middle)'!B:B,'Middle Master'!A2,INDEX('Student Survey (Middle)'!G:XCC,0,ROW()-3),"agree")
```